# knockout using total of one column in the calculation of another in the same table

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am looking to do the following.  I want to use the total from column 1 in a calculated function for column 2.  is there an easy way to do this with knockout and jquery?

```
col1      | col2
---------------------------
1         | .21 * col1_total
10        | .25 * col1_total
20        | .31 * col1_total
----------------------------
col1_total| col2_total
```

Added Code for a better example.  the problem is with the self.col3.  self.col1total isn't available from that portion of the code. How can I get around that?

```
function custdata(data) {
var self = this;
self.col1= ko.observable(data.col1);
self.col2= ko.observable(data.col2);

self.col3= ko.computed(function(){
 return self.col1() * self.col1total();
});
}


function guideviewmodel() {
var self = this;
self.custlist = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.col1total = ko.computed(function () {
            var total = 0;
            $.each(self.custlist(), function () { total += this.col1(); });
            return total;
        });

        self.custlist.removeAll();
                    $.getJSON(callPath + "/api/xxx?guid=" + $("#lblFilteredID").text(), function (allData) {
                        var mappedLogs = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new custdata(item) });
                        self.custlist(mappedLogs)
                    });
}
```

Comment: Did you take a look at ko.computed? (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)

Comment: to use the ko.computed in the function(data) (mapping part) you can't access the ko.computed function that gets the total from the viewmodel part. So the total isn't computed until after the rows are generated using that method.  my sort of workaround is calling the same array twice, once to get a total. then assigning that to an label, then referencing that labels result in the data mapping section.  It's clunky though and doesn't seem to always work.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a fiddle according to your requirement check it out,

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsbin.com/esakiy/4/edit).

Comment: I think this works.  The program is structured a little different. Let me see if I can apply it. current structure
function(data){
var self = this;
self.col1 = ko.observable(data.col1);}
function viewmodel(){
self.a1 = ko.observablearray([]);
function to total cols
function to get data 
}

Comment: looks like I need to pull my .computed out of my function(data) and put it all in the view model...

Comment: Added Code to Clarify. This Fiddle doesn't work with how my program is set up. not sure how to modify it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? im not sure how you want to calculate the percentage to multiply column 2 by. Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/G7dye/

```
<div>
<span data-bind="text:$root.columns().length"></span>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:columns">
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind ='text:num'></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text:col2"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
var TableItem = function(c){
var self = this;
 this.num = ko.observable(c);
this.col2 = ko.computed(function(){
    return (self.num() * .21);
});
}

var ViewModel = function(){
var self = this;
this.columns = ko.observableArray([new TableItem(5),new TableItem(3)]);
this.columnOneTotal = ko.computed(function(){
    var colOneTot = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.columns(), function(column) {
        colOneTot += column.num();
    });
    return colOneTot;
});
 this.columnTwoTotal = ko.computed(function(){
    var colTwoTot = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.columns(), function(column) {
        colTwoTot += column.col2();
    });
    return colTwoTot;
});
```

}

```
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: If I am reading this right, it's not quite what I mean.  col1 and col2 have values.  col2's value is the total of col1 * it's unique value from the dataset.  In your example your just multiplying it by .21 not the total of col1